# How to structure an Angular 2 front end app along with Flask back-end api?

Tags: ubuntu, angular, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I want to serve the front-end angular 2 app using Nginx. I'm using Gunicorn as a medium between Nginx and Flask. I want to deploy this web app for production. What should be the proper app structure to do so? Also, what will be the nginx server block config? I'm hosted on a digital ocean Linux based droplet(Ubuntu 16.04).  I've referred the following links, but they seem to be using Flask to serve the front end as well. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample Nginx config file. I'm sure this is not the best way to do this, but it got me testing my app.

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        # Your angular app
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # Static files 
        location /static {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/flask/static;
        }

        # Gunicorn 
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }   
    }
```

**Points to Note**

1. Use Angular CLI to build your Angular app to say, `dist` folder. Make nginx point to it. Given as `/usr/share/nginx/html` in the config. This [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects) helped me figure out Angular CLI better.
2. Serve your flask backend using gunicorn. Say, `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:4000 app:app`. Routed to `/api`.
3. Configure nginx to reverse proxy to gunicorn. Given in the code.

Hope this at least gets you going.